# Understanding where X11 fonts come from

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, xorg

In my older Ubuntu, there used to be the fonts

```
-b&h-lucidatypewriter-* ...
```

However, in my new Ubuntu 18.04, I don't have it any more.

So I booted into my older Ubuntu, and try to find it, but this all that I can get:

```
$ fc-list | grep -i lucida | wc 
      0       0       0

$ apt-cache search lucida | wc 
      0       0       0

$ mlocate lucida | wc 
      0       0       0
```

I need to know which *package* and which *file* contains that font. How to do that? Thx.

Comment: Did you try asking the package manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of the Xorg core bitmap fonts package, `xfonts-100dpi` and `xfonts-75dpi`. The file names are `/usr/share/fonts/X11/*/lu*.pcf.gz`.

There are two kinds of fonts in X11: server-side (drawn by the X server, shown in `xlsfonts`) and client-side (drawn by the application, shown in `fc-list`). Fonts named as in your example are very likely to be server fonts in `.pcf` format.

(Although technically Xorg can render text using TTF/OTF fonts and FreeType/fontconfig understands X11 BDF/PCF bitmaps, the results are rather ugly and so they usually aren't configured to look inside each other's font directories.)

Answer (score 1):

I found
[this answer](https://iambvk.wordpress.com/2007/10/29/lucidatypewriterbitmap-fonts-in-ubuntu/)
from 2007, which might still be true :

> By default Ubuntu comes with bitmap fonts disabled in the system.
>   Since lucidatypewriter is a bitmap font, it doesn’t show up in the
>   font chooser windows. You need to enable bitmap fonts to use it.
>
> To enable bitmap fonts, follow the below procedure.
>
> 1. Run the below command in the terminal, and choose “YES” when it asks for “enable bitmap fonts?” question. Choose the defaults for
>      other queries.
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-confg
>    ```
> 2. Once you do the above step, you should regenerate the font cache using below command.
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
>    ```
> 3. Now you should logout and re-login. Now bitmap fonts start appearing on the font chooser dialog boxes.